# No such file or directory when mount nfsv4 from kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes

I am mounting an NFS file system directory from my Kubernetes pod, this is the PV yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs-jenkins-pv
  namespace: infrastrcuture
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 8Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  mountOptions:
    - vers=4.0
  nfs:
    server: "192.168.31.2"
    path: "/home/dolphin/data/k8s/monitoring/infrastructure/jenkins"
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
```

and this is my NFS `/etc/exports` file:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv ~]$ cat /etc/exports
/ *(rw,fsid=0,sync,insecure_locks,insecure,no_root_squash)
/home/dolphin/data/k8s/monitoring/infrastructure/jenkins *(rw,fsid=1000,sync,insecure_locks,insecure,no_root_squash)
```

why the nfs server give me tips `No such file or directory`? what should I do to fix? this is the full error log:

```
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "nfs-jenkins-pv" : mount failed: exit status 32 Mounting command: systemd-run Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/fbbd2507-3c3b-49fa-a646-46748290f007/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/nfs-jenkins-pv --scope -- mount -t nfs -o vers=4.0 192.168.31.2:/home/dolphin/data/k8s/monitoring/infrastructure/jenkins /var/lib/kubelet/pods/fbbd2507-3c3b-49fa-a646-46748290f007/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/nfs-jenkins-pv Output: Running scope as unit: run-rde3824064fc74a3c91262071353346d3.scope mount.nfs: mounting 192.168.31.2:/home/dolphin/data/k8s/monitoring/infrastructure/jenkins failed, reason given by server: No such file or directory
```

Comment: try a different directory may be one with smaller path , also  check the permissions on directory.

Comment: Have you tried create the mount dir manually to test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I define my `/etc/exports` file like this:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv alertmanager]$ cat /etc/exports
/home/dolphin/data/k8s *(rw,fsid=0,sync,insecure_locks,insecure,no_root_squash)
/home/dolphin/data/k8s/infrastructure/jenkins *(rw,fsid=1000,sync,insecure_locks,insecure,no_root_squash)
/home/dolphin/data/k8s/monitoring/alertmanager *(rw,fsid=1001,sync,insecure_locks,insecure,no_root_squash)
```

and the PV yaml like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs-jenkins-pv
  namespace: infrastrcuture
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 8Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  mountOptions:
    - vers=4.0
  nfs:
    server: "192.168.31.2"
    path: "/infrastructure/jenkins"
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
```

works.